# Fixing background image to 100% on Crystal Report

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, crystal-reports

I am making a crystal report where i need to set a background image. I did it but when i open that report on Large screen the image stays in same size, Like it isn't automatically increasing size as screen size. And when i open it on small screen it isn't automatically getting smaller. I want to set it to 100% on every screen.
I am using Crystal Report version 13.0.22

Answer (score 0):

Image size in Crystal can be static, can adapt to the size of the actual image loaded dynamically, or can be sized via formula logic.

Using formula logic will not work for you unless you create/get a UFL that provides a function for detecting the screen size.

But you can place an image with a different size, corresponding to the screen size, on each machine, load that image dynamically using the 'Graphic Location' expression, and turn on the 'Can Grow' property.

Comment: You mean i need to use separate images for different screen resolutions? Can't I work with only one image? and it grows and shrinks as my screen goes big or small.